# How to write a single piece of code running both on route A (mounted hook) and also when arriving at route A?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Currently in order for me to do a thing X either when loading route A or arriving to route A, I need to write X twice:

```
watch: {
  $route (to, from){
    if (to.name === 'simulation-step-3-sequence') {
      EventBus.$emit('actionIsSortable');
    }
  }
},
async mounted () {
  if (this.$route.name === 'simulation-step-3-sequence') {
    EventBus.$emit('actionIsSortable');
  }
}
```

Is there a way to simplify this so I write X (the emit line) only once?

Answer (score 0):

This technique is really needed only in two cases - multiple routes are using same component or dynamic routes (with parameters) ...see the [docs](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/essentials/dynamic-matching.html#reacting-to-params-changes)

In this cases when the new route is using same component as the old route, Vue Router will just reuse existing component instance.

1. You can place a `key` on `router-view` and disable this behavior. Your site will be less effective but you can get rid of `$route` watcher

```html
<router-view :key="$route.fullPath" />
```

2. Other option is to change watcher definition like this:

```js
watch: {
    $route: {
      immediate: true,
      handler: function(to, from) {
        console.log(`Route changing from '${from}' to '${to}'`);
      }
    }
  }
```

Vue will call watcher handler on route changes but also when the component is created (so you can remove the code in lifecycle hook)